# How to forward an incoming connection through a vpn to internet

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, proxy, forwarding

I'll try to illustrate my problem as thoroughly as possible.

So we have a limited internet connection for our mobile networks via 4G or LTE but cable connections such as ADSL and Fibre are not limited.

The limited connection only allows to connecting to certain domains on the internet. The overall scheme is in the picture below. What I'm trying to do is try to connect my cell phone, which is a client with limited connectivity, to my PC at home server which is not limited through a proxy and then make my PC that is connected to a VPN route all the traffic coming from the client through the VPN to the internet. I am using CCProxy to do this.

Basically, I'm trying to to get around the limited connection by connecting to a proxy server that is not affected by the limitations and making that proxy connect me to the desired VPN to eventually connect to the internet. I hope I described my problem correctly and thanks for any suggestions.

[image: What I'm trying to do :)]

Comment: You described what you want to do well enough. But you’ve not provided any information about what you’ve tried, or how you currently configured the system and / or what is not working as expected. It basically looks like you want a tutorial on this broad subject. But the stack exchange sites are for clearly detailed questions with specific answers that show a level of self research. You can find plenty of tutorials elsewhere. Please see [ask]. You might look up the difference between a full tunnel and a split tunnel to get started.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do this and that's why I asked in the first place. I'll try searching for the tunnel as you suggested and see what comes up.